# Use one or more endpoints for 1 django app

Tags: django, web-applications, endpoint

Im working on a web application.
single-page.
There are different elements of the site, which reload data or do mathematical operation on it (in the backend). --> this data does only appear as "meta-data" in the menu of the site. 
All received data shown in the menu are always used to create one or more charts/plots.

Question:
I get different type of data. Should I use multiple endpoints like .../get_data_type1/....
.../get_data_type2/...
...
or should I use 1 general endoint
.../get_data/...
and use IF and ELSE in the code, to figure out, which data is requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the data you are requesting and the number of conditionals. If its big, split it up. If it's not, you can do it in one single endpoint.

You should consider your near future, so do it simple and easy to adapt to your future requirements.